# How can I apply jQuery statements to elements that are loaded in runtime?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web page with one button and one div.  If you click this button that will load another button into the div using jQuery.  I found that the new button -which is loaded in runtime - will not be affected by other jQuery statements.

How can I apply jQuery statements to elements that are loaded in runtime?

I hope It is clear. if not I will try to give an example.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are attaching an event to a selector that matches something in the dynamically loaded DIV before the DIV is loaded, you need to use jQuery's [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) functionality so that it knows to look for new content to attach these handlers to. If that's not your problem, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind events to the new button when it's loaded:

$(element).bind("click", function(){
   //enter code for the new button
})